# How can I get whether models.CharField is checked or not?

Tags: python, django

I want to know whether models.CharField is checked or not.

I wrote in models.py like

```
class Check(models.Model):
    STATUS = {
        'A': '1',
        'B': '2',
    }
    Check = (
        (STATUS['A'], 'a'),
        (STATUS['B'], 'b'),
    )

    check = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=Check, default=STATUS['A'])
```

in views.py

```
    def check(self):
        check_status = Check.objects
```

I want to check whether STATUS['B'] is checked or not and I want to get all data b is retruned by using only one code

```
check_status = Check.objects
```

But I cannot understand how I should write a code.

Comment: Why are you using the CharField with choices instead of just two BooleanFields? Right now the STATUS['B'] can't be 'checked'. It can only be the value of the check field in the Check model. Do you want to now how you can retrieve the value of of the check field in the Check model?

Comment: I honestly cannot understand what do you want XD
You can get all Check object with B status like this:
Check.objects.filter(check=Check.STATUS['B'])
?
Also, I can advise you to follow Django code style for choice fields if it's possible:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/
For checking status in View, please attach view code.
If you have an object, you can check if the status is И with
obj.check == Check.STATUS['B']
Or to create model class is_b_status with the same checking, that will return True or False and use it in view.